# ConEmu always starts with deleting a OneDrive user profile folder

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, conemu

I have ConEmu installed even before I have upgraded from Win7 to Win10.
For quite a while whenever I start ConEmu without a specific task, the following command gets executed:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /q /c rmdir /s /q "[UserProfile]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\18.212.1021.0008\amd64"
```

I assume this is an artifact left behind by the OneDrive (big?) update. Of course the folder is now long gone (and throgoughly deleted) and whenever ConEmu starts up an error is reported, and the command quits.
Also when I log in a bunch of Command Line windows used to span with simmilar results, however I do not know for sure anymore because of this sad situation I tend not to sit in front of my PC whenever I turn it on and logs in so I don't get to see it.

- There is no task configured in ConEmu spaning this command of course.
  I've also updated the taskbar icon just in case with simmilar result.
- The link does not contain any additional parameters.
- I've also checked `\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun` for both HKCU and HKLC, and only the HKCU points to CLink integration batch file.

ConEmu originally was installed with Chockolatey as well as CLink. I may have upgraded it with an MSI since.

How do I make ConEmu forget this command?
Where does it come from?
Why ConEmu?! Not even CMD.EXE have this behavour!

Comment: What if you run from Win+R: "ConEmu64.exe -basic -run cmd.exe"?

Comment: That works, and spawned a new instance despite another already running. I removed -basic and that works too. "ConEmu64.exe" without any arguments produces the same issue I've described.

Comment: I also have tried "ConEmu64.exe -basic" and that started Far manager instead of the command mentioned in the issue.

Comment: It is in the Settings->Startup->Command Line. I'd write an answer but the only thing I do not understand is the "how?" for me postponding the answer for now. The settings are stored in the ConEmu.xml of my user profile, true but why would OneDrive change it?